# What is the distribution of the sample variance of a chi-square distributed variable?

Tags: distributions, sample

I am conducting an experiment, in which I have a variable that is distributed with a $\chi_k^2$ distribution (for my specific case $k=2$, but a general solution would be nice). I am taking samples of size $n$ of this variable, where I am able to vary $n$. I am taking the variance and mean of each sample, and would like to estimate the uncertainty of these values for each sample. In general, my $n$ is large enough that the distribution of the sample means can be approximated with a normal distribution, as is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Sample_mean), and I am using the standard deviation of this distribution as my uncertainty on the sample mean.

The trouble comes with the sample variance. How is the sample variance distributed? Is there an analytic expression, or at least an approximation for large $n$? Empirically, I have found that the sample variance appears to be distributed normally, but I would prefer to have some expression for this distribution, rather than fitting one to the data numerically.

Comment: Assuming independent samples, $n\bar{X} \sim \chi^2(nk)$, so $\operatorname{E}{\bar X} = k$ & $\operatorname{Var} \bar{X}=\frac{2k}{n}$: you needn't resort to approximation. Deriving the distribution of the sample variance will be a little more involved - but can I ask the point of this experiment? There isn't any uncertainty about each sample mean or sample variance, or about any unknown distribution parameters - no model to be fitted to the data. (If you were estimating $k$ from a sample, the *geometric* mean is the sufficient statistic.)

Answer (score 3):

If $X_1,\ldots,X_N\sim \chi^2_k$, then $\mathbb E[X_i]=k$ and $\mathrm{var}(X_i)=2k$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X_n)^2\Big] &= n \mathbb E[X_1^2]-n\mathbb E[\bar X_n^2]\\
&= n(2k+k^2)-n^{-1}\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\Big)^2\Big]\\
&= n(2k+k^2)-n^{-1} n \mathbb E[X_1^2] - n(n-1)n^{-1} \mathbb E[X_1X_2]\\
&= (n-1)(2k+k^2) -(n-1)\mathbb E[X_1]^2\\
&= (n-1)\{2k+k^2-k^2\}\\
&= (n-1)2k
\end{align*}
and the expected value of the empirical variance is $2k$.

To derive the distribution of $s^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X_n)^2$, consider the change of variable from $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},\bar{x_n})$, with Jacobian $n$. The projection of the above into $s^2$ is unlikely to be available in closed form.